# Why does my while loop end after I type in an score once when I want to type more before it ends

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The issue is that after I enter 1 exam code it automatically exits the loop. I want to enter more exam scores until i type "exit". But whenever i type the first exam code it goes straight to the system.out.printlns at the bottom. Also, if i have made any other mistakes please let me know. Please help

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ExamScoresCalculator{
   
      public static void main(String[] args){
      
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // an instance of the scanner class
      
      boolean scoreError = true;
      double examScoreLow;
      double examScoreHigh;
      double examScoreTotal = 0; 
      int numOfEntries = 0;
      int entryScore;
      
      System.out.println( "Enter the lowest possible exam score" ); // user input instructions
      examScoreLow = scan.nextInt();
      
      System.out.println( "Enter the highest possible exam score" ); // user input instructions
      examScoreHigh = scan.nextInt();
              
      while(scoreError == true){
         
         System.out.println("Enter an exam score or type exit"); // asking user to input an exam score
         entryScore = scan.nextInt(); 
         
         String entryNums = "";
         entryNums = Integer.toString(entryScore);
                      
      if(entryNums==( "EXIT") || entryNums==( "Exit") || entryNums==( "exit" )){
         scoreError = false;
      }else{
           entryScore = Integer.parseInt(entryNums); //converting user input into a number
           
         if(entryScore < examScoreHigh && entryScore > examScoreLow){ //checking in entry is in range
            numOfEntries++; // updating number of exam score entries
            examScoreTotal = entryScore;
            ++examScoreTotal;
  
            if (entryScore < examScoreLow){ // checking if entry is less than highest exam score
                examScoreLow = scan.nextInt();
            }
            if (entryScore > examScoreLow){  
            } 
         }else{  
          System.out.println( "Not a valid exam score, please try again"); // asking user to input an 
                                                                                             exam score
          scan.nextInt();         
         }       
       }//closing first else
       }//closing while loop
       
       System.out.println("The total number of exam scores is: " + numOfEntries);
       System.out.println("The lowest exam score is: " + examScoreLow);
       System.out.println("The highest exam score is : " + examScoreHigh);
       System.out.println("The average exam score is : " + examScoreTotal / numOfEntries);
        
      }//closing main method
 }//closing classimport java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: HINT: start by getting rid of every line of code containing `entryScore`, and replace `String entryNums = "";` with `String entryNums = scan.nextLine();`.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: As an additional note, don't say `scoreError == true`; it's already a boolean. Just `while (scoreError)` or `while (!scoreError)`.